# Is stomach acid from healthy food different from unhealthy food?

Tags: digestion, stomach

This is maybe a weird question but let me try to explain it.

Once healthy food (vegetables, fruits, healthy oil's etc.) reaches the stomach the acids kick's in to break the food further. Is the stomach acid combined with healthy food the same as stomach acid combined with unhealthy food?

The endpoint is that I'm trying to find out will stomach acid combined with healthy food make less damage to the esophagus than the stomach acid combined with unhealthy food or is stomach acid just stomach acid no matter which type of food  it interacts with?

Comment: This seems like it would be an impossible question to answer definitively, as the definition of "healthy food" vs. "unhealthy food" is far too vague.

Comment: Stomach acid is stomach acid. How much damage it does to your esophagus depends on how much ends up there and how often, not what "kind" it is.

Comment: @CareyGregory Don't ignore the status of the mucosa/epithelium.  What the acid is hitting is important too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stomach acid does not react with foods in the way that it would form harmful chemical complexes. The acid affects pepsinogen - it helps to convert it in its active form pepsin, which is the enzyme that breaks down proteins.

https://www.reference.com/science/pepsinogen-converted-pepsin-3f6a6755935d1c0f

If your question is about acid reflux and how to prevent damage of the esophagus by acid, you may want to know which foods decrease the tonus of the lower esophageal sphincter (LES) and thus allow reflux of the acid. Examples of such foods are chocolate, fatty foods in general, and foods with peppermint. Other things that irritate the esophagus include spicy and acidic foods, tea, coffee and smoking.

https://www.gicare.com/diets/gerd/

So, in case you have acid reflux, the above foods may be unhealthy for you, even if they are not unhealthy by themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a big difference, it differs  in our [metabolism, the number of enzymes and the time of digestion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metabolism). Why?
**Let's break it down.**

[Stomach acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gastric_acid) is a digestive fluid, formed in the stomach and is composed of hydrochloric acid (HCl) .05–0.1 M (roughly 5,000–10,000 parts per million or 0.5-1%)[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gastric_acid) potassium chloride (KCl) and sodium chloride (NaCl).
The acid plays a key role in the digestion of proteins, by activating digestive enzymes, and making ingested proteins unravel so that digestive enzymes break down the long chains of amino acids.

Since we now know the meaning of stomach acid, let's categorize healthy foods and unhealthy foods. So by doing that let's give an example; fruits and vegetables are considered as [healthy foods](https://behealthy.today/healthy-foods-weight-loss/), right? and junk foods, noodles, and some processed foods are unhealthy.
So here's the thing, healthy foods like [fruits and veggies contain enzymes](https://saveourbones.com/stop-bad-digestion-and-poor-nutrient-absorption-with-these-3-easy-tricks/) that will help the process of digestion meaning, these enzymes plus the enzymes produced by our body can digest and break down these foods easily.

> Whereas according to [Mercola.com](http://articles.mercola.com/sites/articles/archive/2015/04/29/junk-food-metabolism.aspx), the instant-noodle consumers
>   had a significantly lower intake of important nutrients like protein,
>   calcium, phosphorus, iron, potassium, vitamin A, niacin, and vitamin C
>   compared with non-consumers.7 Those who ate instant noodles also had
>   an excessive intake of energy, unhealthy fats, and sodium (just one
>   package may contain 2,700 milligrams of sodium).
>
> Not to mention, refined carbohydrates like breakfast cereals, bagels,
>   waffles, pretzels, and most other processed foods quickly break down
>   to sugar in your body. This increases your insulin and leptin levels
>   and contributes to insulin resistance, which is the primary underlying
>   factor of nearly every chronic disease and a condition known to man,
>   including weight gain.
>
> Not only that but remember… when you eat junk food you are not just
>   feeding yourself… you’re feeding your microbiome, too, and in so doing
>   altering its construction for better or worse. Your body’s diverse
>   army of microbes is responsible for many crucial biological processes,
>   from immunity to memory to mental health, so feeding it wisely, with
>   fresh unprocessed and naturally fermented foods is crucial to your
>   overall health and well-being.
>
> "Research published in the Journal of Nutrition found that women who
>   consumed more instant noodles had a significantly greater risk of
>   metabolic syndrome than those who ate less, regardless of their
>   overall diet or exercise habits."

Study shows that processed foods are harder to digest than healthy foods like fruits and veggies.

**Check these:**

http://foodbabe.com/2012/08/01/theres-proof-processed-foods-are-harder-to-digest/
https://www.liverdoctor.com/the-best-and-worst-foods-for-a-fast-metabolism/

By the way regarding with:

> The endpoint is that I'm trying to find out will stomach acid combined
>   with healthy food make less damage to the esophagus

It is only possible if you have [acid reflux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gastroesophageal_reflux_disease).